# Error when adding Jar to Maven project

Tags: maven-2, jar

I've added a jar to the 'Referenced Libraries' section in Eclipse, which now allows me to see objects from this jar when coding. However when I build with maven, I keep getting `The import ____ cannot be resolved` errors.

How do I fix this? Do I have to add in the `pom.xml`? I'm trying use `smartgwt.jar`.

Also - What would be the 'proper' way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer suggests, you should use eclipse *or* maven. Maven has a useful `eclipse:eclipse` target that can be used to generate an eclipse project that can be imported in eclipse.

I found this example on http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=12 Should be worth a try.

Basically, update your pom.xml with

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>gwt-maven-plugins</id>
        <url>http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>    
<repositories>        
    <repository>
        <id>gwt-maven</id>
        <url>http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>smartclient</id>
        <name>smartclient.com</name>
        <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

And add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @belgarat: Correct answer for specifying the right repository :)

Answer (score 2):

Maven doesn't have any knowledge of things that are not declared in the `pom.xml` so, yes, you have to declare smartgwt in the POM. Actually, the common way to work with Maven and IDEs is to add things in the POM and to generate or derive things at the IDE level from the POM. In the case of Eclipse, this can be done using the maven-eclipse-plugin or [**M2Eclipse**](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) (the later would be my recommendation here and supports bi-directional actions).

Having all that said, the fact is that smartgwt isn't distributed in Maven central repository so you'll have to add its repository (where to find it) **and** the dependency.

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>SmartGWT</id>
      <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version><!-- or whatever version you're using -->
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The smartgwt project somehow provides some (outdated) documentation in [HowToEclipseGWTMaven](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-ea/wiki/HowToEclipseGWTMaven).

Answer (score 1):

You should manage your dependencies either through Eclipse OR through maven. Maven has a nice utility to create Eclipse project files, and there's a plugin to manage the pom file in Eclipse.

To specifically solve you problem, you need to find the artifactId and groupId (and possibly the version as well) for the jar you want. Then add this to the pom file. Then maven will build correctly.